# c prog of tcp/ip client server .in server counts how many clients visited to the server.it works for multiple clients at same time

Tags: disconnect

I already tried the server prog  but server can't distinguish between the clients please help me.

A client server program in which server counts the no of client's visited to the server.
Server handles the multiple client at same time.

Answer (score 0):

A connection is always uniquely identified by two things: The "clients" address/port, and the "servers" address/port. The most common way to uniquely identify a client is to use its address/port pair.

Or if you just want to have a simple but unique small integer value, you can use the fact that the most common implementations use just a small integer value for the actual socket.

In C++ you could, for example, use a [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to store the data for each connection. Use the socket as the key, and a structure containing the needed data for the map data.

In C you most likely use a simple single-link list for the connection data, each structure containing the socket. To find the data corresponding to a specific socket just iterate over the list to find it.